# Помогите с onCreateView

Tags: android, java

Button ссылается на фрагмент:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment1(){

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return  rootView;
    }
}
```

в XML fragment1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.sviter.myapplication.Fragment1">

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.sviter.myapplication.TestListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/number_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.67"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

В TestListFragment обычный список:

```
public class TestListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.number_list_array, R.layout.list_item);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String value = (String) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        ItemFragment fragment = ItemFragment.newInstance(value);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
        ft.addToBackStack(value);
        ft.replace(R.id.number_container,fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }
}
```

В стэктрэйсе вот что:

```
10-20 03:02:54.845  10703-10703/com.example.sviter.myapplication E/MainActivity﹕ Error in creating fragment
10-20 03:03:03.633  10703-10703/com.example.sviter.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 225K, 3% free 9516K/9772K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
10-20 03:03:38.127  10703-10703/com.example.sviter.myapplication E/MainActivity﹕ Error in creating fragment
10-20 03:03:39.478  10703-10703/com.example.sviter.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 298K, 4% free 9730K/10060K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
10-20 03:09:33.974  12220-12220/com.example.sviter.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-20 03:09:34.124  12220-12220/com.example.sviter.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
10-20 03:09:34.154  12220-12220/com.example.sviter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-20 03:09:36.236  12220-12220/com.example.sviter.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-20 03:09:36.236  12220-12220/com.example.sviter.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4160cba8)
10-20 03:09:36.246  12220-12220/com.example.sviter.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sviter.myapplication, PID: 12220
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.sviter.myapplication.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:19)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #10: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.sviter.myapplication.MainListPhotoshop
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4759)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.sviter.myapplication.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:19)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Короче, ругается на onCreateView, как я понимаю! Помогите.

Answer (score 1):

[Фрагмент во фрагменте нельзя объявлять через xml](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Comment: А как надо?

Comment: @sviter-pro, [вставить его туда программно][1], например...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10122958

Comment: Прошу прощения за наглость! Я просто новичок (учусь на курсах). А как программно это туда вставить???

Comment: @sviter-pro пройдите по ссылке